# Flash Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript, designer, graphic

I have a problem in browser, it means i have made one flash swf file with action script 3. It is working in my system but it is not working in my friend's system. It shows round round like loading type. When I change public setting action script 2, it is working but some errors happened due to coding.How can I solve this problem without change the version.

Comment: This is too general! Specify what errors, what's wrong.. Maybe your friend uses browser from 19th century? Or maybe you need to tweak your embed tags? Or bwaah..

Answer (score 0):

assuming when you say that it works on your machine you mean in your browser and not locally, try getting your friend to update their flash player to the latest version. when you say it works when you change to as2, it sounds like they've got an old version

Comment: thanks for your answer. we already updated the latest version of flash player and also browser. we tried ie8, firefox 4.0 and chrome. but same result in all. i checked another system it is ok. how can i change my code as3 to as2 (equivalent code). code for mouse click event for a button  stop();

function goHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("home");
}
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome);

Comment: hm, thats weird. are you trying to do anything special? maybe access a file that's on your computer but not his? do you have a specific error that's coming up? button code in as2 is something like `home.onClick = function(){ gotoAndStop("home");} i think

Comment: it is working on my another friend's system. I tried three of them it works with one. same files are sent to all. no any specific error. ok once again thanks for your answer i will try with as2.

Comment: Are you testing this locally, or through a browser? If it's locally, then flash player will block some actions (loading files etc) unless the swf is in a trusted folder. You can set these folders in the security manager settings: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html - just add a folder in the "Always trust files in these locations" dialog.

Comment: you can also listen for security and io errors on actions like loading files, that can give you a hint of what's wrong.